# I could not able to call one IBaction on click of alertView button

Tags: ios, ios7

I have an alertView declared in a method like this.

```
UIAlertView* alertView =[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Check In Alert" message:@"Are you sure he/she is there?" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Yes" otherButtonTitles:@"No", nil];
                        alertView.tag = sender;
                        [alertView show];
```

So in alertView method of clickedButtonIndex I have this code.

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    if([alertView.title isEqualToString:@"Check In Alert"])
    {
        ClassRoomParticipant *clsrp;
        NSMutableArray *data = nil;
        data=[self.presentDataArray objectAtIndex:0];
        clsrp = (ClassRoomParticipant *)[data objectAtIndex:alertView.tag];
        NSLog(@"Do Nothing");
        if (buttonIndex == 0)
        {

            [clsrp setGetParcpntCheckInStatus : 2];// Checked in by Teacher

        }
        else if (buttonIndex == 1)
        {

            [clsrp setGetParcpntCheckInStatus : 3];// Not checked in by Teacher, still Absent

        }
        return;
    }
    NSString *title = [alertView buttonTitleAtIndex:buttonIndex];

    if([title isEqualToString:@"OK"])
    {
        [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    }
    else if([title isEqualToString:@"Button 2"])
    {
        //NSLog(@"Button 2 was selected.");
    }
    else if([title isEqualToString:@"Button 3"])
    {
        //NSLog(@"Button 3 was selected.");
    }
}
```

I have a method like this.

```
-(void)changeStudentAction:(id)sender
{
    CustomUIButton *button=sender;
    NSInteger flag = 0;
    if (button.selected)
    {
        [button setSelected:NO];
        [button setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Absent_on_coloured.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        flag=0;
    }
    else
    {
        [button setSelected:YES];
        [button setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Present_on_coloured.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        flag=1;
    }

    if (button.collectionIdentifier == ClsRmPrctPresntCollectionView)
    {
        [self ModifyDataArray:button.taggy flag:flag identifier:ClsRmPrctPresntCollectionView change:@"Button" toDate:nil section:button.section];
        [self modifyCollectionArray:PRESENT processingData:self.presentDataArray identifier:ClsRmPrctPresntCollectionView index:button.taggy section:button.section];
    }

    self.isAnyChangesHappened=YES;
}
```

I want to call this changeStudentAction method inside of alertView button click "Yes".When I am calling this method inside buttonIndex==0, it gives me error. Can you please tell me how to call this method inside the alertview.

Answer (score 0):

1) Create an outlet of the "`CustomUIButton`" for which "`changeStudentAction`" is action

2) in alert view delegate call `[self changeStudentAction:self.customUIbuttonOutlet]`

Answer (score 0):

I guess it is showing you error because of `alertView.tag = sender;` statement. Make sure `sender` is integer.

Also you did not set delegate of alertView. Try this : `alertView.delegate = self;`

Rest all is seems to be perfect. Just call `changeStudentAction` method in the correct block of `- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex` method.

Comment: I have set delegate for alertView. Now I want to call the changeStudentAction method inside alertView.Can I call like this                     if (buttonIndex == 0)
        {
            [self changeStudentAction:(id)clsrp];
        }
But it is crashing.Showing "Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[ClassRoomParticipant isSelected]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7a7b7ac0"

Comment: Its because your variable 'clsrp' is of 'ClassRoomParticipant' class. Where as you are mapping this variable to 'CustomUIButton' in 'changeStudentAction' method, which is invalid.